# Style component selector DOM element

Tags: css, angular

I've got a component hierarchy:

```
appParent.html
    <app-parent>
      <div class="someDiv"> // has width and height set
        <app-child></app-child>
      </div>
    </app-parent>
```

appChild.html:

```
  <div class="childWrapper"></div>
```

I would like to style `app-child` to have width an height equal to its container. My ultimate goal is to have `.childWrapper` the same width and height as `.someDiv`, but I do not want to bring JS into business

I applied

```
app-child{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

but `app-child` remains `0x0px`. I tried setting some random width and heights and `app-child` remains `0x0px` at all times. Applying styles to `.someDiv` works as expected.

What is going on here? Why can't styles be applied to component selectors?

Answer (score 0):

Given the above CSS on the child, it IS taking up 100% of the parent's height. The problem is that the parent does not have an explicit height set. Try setting the height of someDiv.

See this codepen: [Full height child div](https://codepen.io/gelder_ux/pen/xPddOe)

```
.someDiv {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}

.childWrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry, I didn't explicitly say that some div is already styles and has with and height set.

Comment: Ah I see, you did allude to it so I should have noticed. Have you tried using the childWrapper class for your height:100%, instead of the app-child tag selector?

Comment: nope still nothing. This appears to be angular specific

Comment: You could try a child selector approach (not ideal, I know):

.someDiv > div:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}